Where do we draw the line on when an edit is reasonable and when the question needs to be re-asked?
Some background to clarify my question: This stems from a recent experience I had on SO where I absolutely made an error in my question statement and inadvertently flipped two terms that I had backward in my head. Luckily, several members of the community caught my error and discussed it in the comments which prompted me to edit my original post, flipping the terms, to correctly ask what I intended.
The problem was, when I made my edit, someone had already given an answer that was true and accurate in response to my initial post, and thus my edit invalidated that answer. It was suggested in the comments that I revert my question and re-ask, which I began to do, but then another user pointed out that because my error was obvious enough that several community members caught it, the edit was valid.
Ultimately, I got the answer I needed, but there was some confusion. So, my question is, how do we decide when an edit is acceptable, or when the question needs to be entirely re-asked? When is it ok for an edit to invalidate accurate answers, if ever? What burden of clarification do folks answering have to ensure they're addressing the spirit of the question? Or, more specifically, is there/what is the precedent for handling these situations?

It's good that you're thinking about this, but I doubt you'll get a definitive answer.

A pile of very handsome questions, but a lot of that has been covered ad nauseum. Add one more question to your pile: how much effort are you supposed to do to know all these things before committing your first questions? Answer: you have more reading to do I'm afraid. Existing meta posts are probably more informative than the help center, especially the faq.

What’s to stop you from editing the good answer to bring it into alignment with the revised question?

@pjs: You're not supposed to edit someone else's answer such that it conflicts with the author's original intent. The person who posted the answer to the flawed question can of course do it themselves, but if you're taking an answer to a misinterpretation of a confusing question and editing it to be the answer a different question, you'd better be the author of said answer (or it needs to be a community wiki).

If both versions of the question are sensible and the edit would invalidate existing answers, ask a new question instead.
Remember that the question and answers do not exist just for you.

Honestly this is a very elegant answer, I appreciate it. I'm curious if anyone else will come along and share their two cents or particularly personal experience, but I have to agree here.

@CamdanMead And, to be clear, in this case, the original version was not sensible--you were asking how to do something your own code showed you knew how to do. That should not have been answered in the first place, so it was not necessarily you who did something wrong, but the answerer not carefully reading your question.

If the original version of the question is sensible, and it receives a good answer before you realise that you accidentally asked a different question to what you intended, then you should move on, and ask a new question.
However, if the original version is a bit weird and self-contradictory because of your mistake, then you should just fix that mistake.
When an answerer sees a question like that, they should not jump in and post an answer. Questions in that state require clarification from the OP. So potential answerers need to post a comment or two to help the OP get the question into an answererable state.
Answerers can certainly start drafting an answer based on what they think the OP really meant. But they should be cautious about actually posting their answer before the OP has clarified things. If they guessed wrongly, then they may have to make drastic changes to their answer, or delete it entirely.
If someone jumps in with an answer to your question while it's in a self-contradictory state, then that's their problem. That's one of the risks of trying to be a FGITW (Fastest Gun In The West). They may be in such a rush to post an answer that they didn't actually read the question properly, so they don't even realise that the question is flawed.
You don't have to be concerned about invalidating such answers. ;)

Also true, but I wouldn't be surprised if the edit gets shot down in review anyway. Some people see the rules as guidelines which allow for exceptions, and others see only cookie cutter rules and will only see an edit which invalidates existing answers.

Fair point. But a good edit summary comment may offset that. And the OP can also post a brief comment on the answer apologising for the misunderstanding (although reviewers probably won't see that).

The formally correct way is probably to close the question, remove the answer, edit and then reopen. Now if anyone wants to goes those three extra miles...
